# Does a wifi bridged router serve 2 wifi connections at “half” speed each?

Tags: router, bridge

I've got 2 desktops that need to use wifi, since they're not located near my router.

How would speeds compare for the following approaches?

- Bridge a router over wifi, and then have both the desktops plug into that bridged router using standard ethernet cables or
- Buy 2 wifi PCI cards, one for each desktop
  Or should I consider something else?

I'm sure it depends to some extent on what I have for routers, but in general, what would one expect?

Comment: It appears you have no idea on how wifi works. Its not so that when a client connects it eats up the bandwidth. Instead both the client and the router simply broadcast the information where the other receives. When both wifi's are both downloading at the same time, then yes, like with any connection, they get half the speed. But that does not really happen much, so all clients usually experience the full speed wifi can handle because at that request, they're the only device requesting something.

Comment: Hey... thanks for the feedback.... I think it's more of a "dont know how routers work question" than anything. Would the router make 2 separate connections to the main router, or would it make one, and split the connection bandwidth between the 2 clients?

Comment: Wait, I misunderstood you. You are talking about router to router, in that case it will only work on half the bandwidth, and both routers must support it.

Comment: @LPChip - I don't think you are correct - If I understand correctly Brad is wanting to use WIFI to efficiently connect2 PCs which are close together but far from the router.  You would not loose 50% of bandwidth router-to-router, as he is not talking about deploying a repeater.

Comment: @davidgo Are you sure? If Router 1 transmits data to Router 2 over Wifi, and Router 2 transmits that data to the client over wifi, that data is transmitted twice, by router 2, which means half the speed is available. At least, that's how I learned it. If it is wired to the routers, then there obviously is no speed lost.

Comment: Router 2 is NOT transmtting data to the client. The OP proposed to connect the AP client to the clients via Ethernet cable.

Comment: @davidgo I really didn't have my day... Misread that part too... xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bridging a router over WIFI" will generally provide slightly better results - I assume you are aware that that means getting a second device to act as in "AP Client" mode.

That said, having a WIFI card in each PC (assuming there are no distance related issues) will not slow things by 50%, it will only slow things down when both systems want to transmit, along with the (compared to 50% very small) overhead of managing who can talk when.